# PHP equivalent to Perl qq//?

Tags: php, string, quotes, double-quotes

I'm converting some Perl code to PHP and much of it contains complex SQL strings with both single and double quotes. This is easily handled in Perl using the `qq//` quote like so:

```
qq/SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE "MixedCaseColName" = 'string'/
```

The best I can do in PHP is pick either single or double quoting for the sting and then escape one or other type of quotes:

```
"SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE \"MixedCaseColName\" = 'string'"
```

This works fine for short strings, but it's a pain for very long sequences with many quotes to find and escape. Any suggestions on a better way to do this in PHP that's easy as Perl?

Comment: See: http://php.net/language.types.string for how to handle quoting string in PHP. The heredoc method comes in handy for not having to worry about single or double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Not as handy or compact as the Perl quote operators, but there is a method of quoting that permits both single and double quotes without escaping. It's called *heredoc*.

An example:

```
<?php

$string = <<<EOT

SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE "MixedCaseColName" = 'string'

EOT;

?>
```

You can name the identifier whatever you want, as long as you use only alphanumeric and underscore characters and not start with a number.

It's important to note that the first identifier must be the last thing on the line and the last identifier, along with the semi-colon, must be the ONLY thing on the line, nothing before or after, no spaces indents, nothing.

More on that here: http://php.net/language.types.string

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, PERL has heredoc quoting too but that sucks up two additional lines of code and requires the string to be left justified. I'd really prefer something that keeps the code tight and properly indented.

Comment: and heredocs leave a newline on the end of the string (at least in Perl)

Comment: @steevithak No there's anything like "qq" in PHP. The closest approach is HEREDOCS

Comment: I'm sure that heredoc leaves a line return at the end, but I've not had a problem using PHP heredoc with SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use heredoc syntax: `<<<`. After this operator, an identifier is provided, then a newline. The string itself follows, and then the same identifier again to close the quotation.

The closing identifier must begin in the first column of the line. Also, the identifier must follow the same naming rules as any other label in PHP: it must contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores, and must start with a non-digit character or underscore.

Try with this example:

```
<?php

$query = <<<EOD
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE "MixedCaseColName" = 'string'/
EOD;

echo $query;

?>
```

Read more at:

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: @steevithak you got some advance?

Answer (score -4):

Please take a look at [`perldoc perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-value-constructors). It explains how Perl processes single- and double-quoted strings, which very much like bash strings.

`q/.../` and `qq/.../` are equivalent to `'...'` and `"..."` but allow for the delimiter to be changed so that embedded quotation marks don't need to be escaped.

Comment: This isn't the slightest bit helpful and does not address the question at all.